# Calculadora mas de dos operadores

Tags: c#

hice una calculadora y funciona, la operacion la hice desde una clase para suma,resta,div,mult. pero no logro poner mas de dos operadores  ya que en el input se debe mostrar así por ejemplo:
4+5*1 -> Despues borra y el resultado de la operacion al poner =
el boton de = lo tengo así:

```
   segundo = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            double Sum;
            double Res;
            double Mult;
            double Div;
            switch (operacion)
            {
                case "+":
                    Sum = objecto4.Sumar((primer),(segundo));
                    textBox1.Text = Sum.ToString();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    Res = objecto3.Restar((primer), (segundo));
                    textBox1.Text = Res.ToString();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    Mult = objecto2.Multiplicacionn((primer), (segundo));
                    textBox1.Text = Mult.ToString();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    Div = objecto.Divisionn((primer), (segundo));
                    textBox1.Text = Div.ToString();
                    break;
```

Otro detalle es que al poner el primer operador si lo pone pero al poner el segundo operador me manda este error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si en el TextBox ingresas valores numericos y letras no va a pder convertir a numerico cuando apliques el parse, deberias poner los numero en campos separados a las operaciones

Si deberias poder hacer un split de los numeros de las operaciones y parsear la cadena para conocer que operaciones se estan realizando

[Writing a Simple Math Expression Engine in C#](https://medium.com/@toptensoftware/writing-a-simple-math-expression-engine-in-c-d414de18d4ce)

a donde apunto es que deberias escribir un parser de la expresion y no solo aplicar la conversion a numerico, porque si mezclas letras y numeros va a fallar.

Otra alternativa

[NCalc-Edge](https://github.com/pitermarx/NCalc-Edge/wiki)

usando

```
Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
var result = e.Evaluate();
```